# Can I use a computer as the processing unit of a video camera instead of the onboard chip?

Tags: video, digital-recording

I have been wondering for a while if we could connect a camera to a computer and let the computer do the processing, that way we would have access to things that the camera wouldn't be able to do independently. For example higher frame rates, higher resolutions, etc.

If a technology like this exists please redirect me to it otherwise I think it should be considered.

Comment: Can you elaborate more of your end objective?

Comment: @Dipan what I intent to do is increase the frame rate on the olympus ep-1 and have the ability to change things like the iso and shutter speed when shooting video. And since the processor in a computer could probably handle more than the processor in a camera, I thing there should be a way to put that to use.

Comment: Well, you can use MatLab and it's video processing toolboxes.. Simply import webcam feed and do your realtime processing.

Answer (score 2):

The processor in your camera is not the only thing you need to override for your proposal to work. Consider the focus system, the iris, and the shutter system, and their respective upper and lower performance boundaries. What you are suggesting appears to be a design up idea not an after it was built idea. In other words you need a whole team of engineers at Olympus at your service to redesign the camera from the ground up. The exception may be, some engineering hack that allows for the higher frame rate perhaps through the firmware.

I am not clear on what you mean by changing the ISO and shutter speed while shooting, do you mean change the ISO or shutter speed in the same take? If so, I've never heard of any camera being able to do that, nor do I understand what you are trying to get?

Comment: What I'm really looking for now is a firmware hack on the Olympus E-p1 to get manual controls on the video. You know, on the 550D for example, you can change the shutter speed, iso, and all that stuff before shooting a video.

Comment: In that case you want to connect with an Olympus users group as they are going to be looking for the same hacks. Thanks for making it clear that the ISO and shutter changes are not in shot but before the shot begins. I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

In some sense, shooting to a raw format with something like a Red camera or an Alexa does what you want.  The camera doesn't do any in-camera image processing to alter the image (except maybe compression), leaving all the data in the original sensor color space.

You can then use your computer to do whatever you want to generate a final image.

ISO can be set in post, for example.  Shutter speed, OTOH, still depends on things like the actual sensor parameters.

There's nothing about the CPU in the camera that would likely be the limiting factor.

If you have some control software for the camera that has useful features like allowing a particular frame rate that the camera vendor doesn't expose in the camera's controls, then it doesn't really matter whether that custom software is running on some frankencamera with a bunch of custom soldering to somehow connect your computer directly to the camera internals, or running directly on the camera.